# Oracle: API for dealing with TNS file?

Tags: oracle, api, tns

Is there an API that will read a TNS file and present it in some easy-to-use data structure?

I would like to get a list of all my TNS entries.  This works but is not particularly elegant!

```
grep '^[a-zA-Z].*=' /etc/tnsnames.ora | sed 's/[ =].*//'
```

Comment: What do you find un-elegant about your solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another, not very simple, solution is ANTLR. You can use ANTLR to parse `tnsnames.ora`. On [ANTLR Grammar List](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) page you will find grammar which can parse `tnsnames.ora`, `sqlnet.ora` and `listener.ora`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if TNSPing would be more useful to you. It will output like:

```
TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
on 01-MAR-2009 02:02:33

Copyright (c) 1997, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = myhostname)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = mydb)))
OK (80 msec)
```

The problem is you must pass it the TNS name to ping, which may or may not be possible in your scenario.